# When the UITabbar is Translucent and the UIViewController is not extended behind the tabbar, the uitabbar seems like covering a black view

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

[image: This is what I want]
[image: This is my problem]

The tabbar in first view is what I want. Because the second view isn't a scrollview, so I can't extend it to bottom by using `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Bottom`.

It looks unacceptable.

And I don't want to set `Translucent` of uitabbar to `false`, it's not fancy.

I try in another way:

`[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];`

It doesn't work. To make it looks more clear, I change the color to red. And the last tabbar also looks like covering some black views.

[image: OK]
[image: OK]

Comment: Please check my answer below, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Consider of the tabbar is translucent, what's the view under the UITabbar view?*

This is the final answer of why it doesn't work when changing the tintcolor of bar. Because the view under UITabbar view is black.

Thanks to the Xcode awesome debugging function. We could locate the view under UITabbar view easily.

[image]

It's UIWindow. So the solution is to simply change the window's `backgroundColor` to white.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, welcome to show my faults in English or anything.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that adding this code in `viewDidLoad` of your viewController will solve your issue:

```
    edgesForExtendedLayout = .all
    extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Plus you can keed your `tabBar` translucent and not set any background color.

Comment: Those line of codes is not related to what the problem is. there intention is to do something else which the app req. don't need which will cause problems.